# Semantic of -> operator in lists (and in general C++)

Tags: c++, list, iterator, operator-overloading

My current assignment is writing a list with iterators. The list isn't being a problem so much as creating the iterator class is.

From a couple of sources I've seen that I have two operators to define in my iterator class:  `operator*` and `operator->`.

Great so far! Supposing my iterator structure is so

```
// Nested class of List
class _Iter
{
private:
    ListElem *pCurr;
    const List *pList;

public:
    _Iter(ListElem *pCurr, const List *list)
        : pCurr_(pCurr), pList(list)
    {}

    T& operator*() { return pCurr_->data; }
    T* operator->() { return &**this; }
};
```

with ListElem being

```
// Nested struct of List
struct ListElem
{
    T data;

    ListElem *next;
    ListElem *prev;
};
```

I can see I'm doing something massively wrong (as double dereferencing of this would lead to a &(*pCurr_->data), which is not dereferencable.

My main problem is not understanding what -> is actually supposed to do in this case. Should it grant the user access to the ListElem class? If that's the case, why can't I just write

```
ListElem *operator->() { return pCurr_; }
```

instead of returning a pointer? My understanding of these two operators as used in my list (and hopefully STL lists) is that:

```
operator*() // Return data pointed to by iterator; pCurr_->data;
operator->() // Grant access to data-holding structure; pCurr;
```

Is this correct, or what am I not getting? (And does `->` have a proper name?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever you do, `(*something).somethingElse` should be equivalent to `something->somethingElse`. The latter is just a short syntax for the former. Therefore,

```
T& operator*() { return pCurr_->data; }
T* operator->() { return &**this; }
```

is fine because `*this` just dereferences `this` which has the type `_Iter*`, not `_Iter`, so no `operator*()` call is done. Then you dereference `*this`, so you get `pCurr->data`, then you take its address, so you get &pCurr->data. But it would be much clearer to just write:

```
T& operator*() { return pCurr_->data; }
T* operator->() { return &pCurr->data; }
```

Now, this

```
ListElem *operator->() { return pCurr_; }
```

is wrong because if `operator*()` returns `T&`, `operator->()` should return `T*`, that's what it was designed for. If you really want to grant access to ListItem instead of its data (which may or may not make sense depending on the design, but in your case it looks like it doesn't), then you should also redefine `operator*()` to get this:

```
ListElem& operator*() { return *pCurr_; }
ListElem *operator->() { return pCurr_; }
```

Note that it is not a language requirement, it is just how you design your class to avoid confusing interface.

Comment: Indeed, I often forget that `this` is actually a pointer. Very annoying :D

Answer (score 1):

`operator->` gives a pointer to the object pointed to by the iterator, in this case (apparently) `pCurr_->data`.

```
T *operator->() { return &(pCurr_->data); }
```

It should return the address of the object returned by `operator*()` as a value or reference.

```
T &operator*() { return pCurr_->data; }
// or
T &operator*() { return *operator->(); }
```

`operator->()` exists to implement `->` with iterators (with the behavior it has for pointers) and is necessary because `operator*` may return an object by value instead of by reference.

Note that you don't need to store a pointer to the `List` in the iterator to obtain the functionality required.

Comment: I have updated my question with the struct ListElem. And aaaah, by providing a pointer to Foo we can now use all of Foos methods! So I'm not returning the ListElem itself, but passing the functionality of the Foo data member on to the user! That makes sense.

Comment: Yep, you're returning the underlying data item for the client to use. Remember that iterators are a generalization of pointers and similarly point to a data item (sometimes very indirectly; I just designed an iterator that holds pointers to polymorphic objects that in turn hold various types of iterators).

Comment: Can I ask why you would need such an iterator?

Comment: I needed an iterator over on-disk collections that can be implemented as various file/database formats. The implementing classes have different kinds of iterators, which are wrapped in a hierarchy of objects. Pointers to these objects are stored in the top-level iterator to get polymorphic behavior. It was a hassle, but conversion of an entire database from one format to another is now a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Your main guideline should be that

```
(*iter).hello();
iter->hello();
```

should both do the same thing. That's what the user expects. Returning ListElem gives nothing to the user. The user shouldn't even know the details of the implementation of ListElem.